# Problems with downloading Composer (PHP) on Macbook?

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, mamp

Before I go on, I'm using MAMP(http://www.mamp.info/en/) and I have a Macbook 10.5.8.

I tried typing `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` in my terminal, but all I get is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in - on line 818
>   curl: (23) Failed writing body.

If I delete the small "s" in `curl -sS`, I get:

> ```
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> 100 32543    0 32543    0     0  25478      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 82387
> ```
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in - on line 818
>
> ```
> 100 48911    0 48911    0     0  32993      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 81518
> ```

but it doesn't do anything.

I even tried to update the path to my PHP thing using this website: "https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693", but my path just stayed the same.

Why is the error happening and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Downloading composer manually (using browser, instead of curl), is that an option? you can still run it with PHP (5.3+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the installed version of PHP is too old. The error is produced by the PHP interpreter (`.. | php`). Composer requires PHP 5.3+, I believe OS X 10.5.8 did not come with PHP 5.3 out of the box.

You probably want to use the PHP install bundled with MAMP, so substitute the `php` executable path at the end of the command. I'm not entirely sure what path that is, but something like:

```
$ curl ... | /Applications/MAMP/bin/.../php
```

I don't know why this didn't work with your path update.
To see which PHP the `php` command resolves to:

```
$ which php
```

And last but not least, make sure any of your php versions are 5.3+ to begin with:

```
$ php -v
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/.../php -v
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!!! It worked!!!! I just used "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php" and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put php client version after | line.
I used:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php56-cli
```

and it works!