# Error installing composer - curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)

Tags: php, linux, bash, symfony, curl

I am trying to install symfony in debian 8 jessie but I have a problem when I execute this instruction in the terminal:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

this is the error message:

> bash: php: no se encontró la orden
>
> curl: (23) Failed writing body (0
>   != 16133)

Can somebody help me?

Thank you.
And sorry for my English

Comment: [Please check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137543/problems-with-downloading-composer-php-on-macbook)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why CURL return and error (23) Failed writing body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16703647/608639)

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
curl -sS → curl -s
```

I has this problem too and find answer [here](http://qiita.com/mapyo/items/1e0077a261340f5d327c)

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/local/php/bin/php
```

Try to PHP fully specified path

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that your php.ini is with openssl active, in my case I'm using Xamp, the configuration file is in the directory:

> C: \ xampp \ php \ php.ini

On line 892, change from:

```
;Extension = php_openssl.dll
```

To

```
Extension = php_openssl.dll
```

Then, you must restart your Apache server in my case by Xampp just click according to the image below:

After that, go to the command prompt (CMD) and enter the following command:

> `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | Php --disable-tls`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer > symfony.phar
sudo mv symfony.phar /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Download Composer installer file from [getcomposer.com](https://getcomposer.org/installer) in your browser, open terminal,  type

```
mv installation /usr/src
```

do that

```
sudo php installer --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer,
```